# GTK Window Centering Not Working Unless Launching Program with sudo

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

This test program compiles and links without problems but will only center the window if I run it as super user as in sudo ./test
I've tried to make a tiny example to illustrate (and hopefully solve) my problem.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and GTK 3.34

```
//  test.c

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 230, 150);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

makefile

```
# compiler
CC := gcc

# warnings
WARN := -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations

CCFLAGS=$(WARN)

GTKLIB=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

# linker
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS= $(GTKLIB)

test: test.o
        $(LD) -o test test.o $(LDFLAGS)

test.o: test.c
        $(CC) -c    $(CCFLAGS) test.c $(GTKLIB) -o test.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o test
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the example in a Wayland session, then this is entirely expected: the `gtk_window_set_position()` function is implemented toolkit-side, and requires that the windowing system provide access to the global screen coordinates—something that Wayland does not have.

If running under `sudo` "works" then it might be a case of GTK selecting the X11 backend, as Wayland won't really work under `sudo`. As a rule, you should **never** run GTK applications under `sudo`, as the code is not audited nor auditable, and you may be opening a security hole the size of the whole session.

In practice, applications should *not* position windows on the desktop; that's the job of the window manager.